# ASP.NET MVC and AngularJS - submitting a dynamic list to the controller

Tags: asp.net, angularjs, controller, asp.net-mvc-5

I don't know how I look for this or how this method is called, but what I am trying to do is adding items dynamically with a form using AngularJS. 
This is all working fine, but how are these items passed to the controller when submitted?

These are snippets from code:

AngularJS part:

```
    angular
    .module('Administration', [])
    .controller('addParents', ['$scope', function ($scope) {

    $scope.parents = [];
    $scope.addParent = function () {
        $scope.parents.push({
            'firstname': $scope.Firstname,
            'lastname' : $scope.Lastname,
            'done': false
        })
        $scope.Firstname = ''
        $scope.Lastname = ''
    }
    $scope.deleteParent = function (index) {
        $scope.parents.splice(index, 1);
    }

}])
```

The list:

```
<div role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true" class="panel-group" id="accordion-1">
 <div class="panel panel-default {'fadeOut' : parent.done}" ng-repeat="parent in parents">
  <div role="tab" class="panel-heading">
   <h4 class="panel-title"><a role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion-1" aria-expanded="true" href="#accordion-1 .item-1">{{parent.firstname}}</a> <span class="fa fa-close pull-right" ng-click="deleteParent($index)"></span></h4>
  </div>
  <div role="tabpanel" class="panel-collapse collapse in item-1">
   <div class="panel-body">
    <fieldset>
     <legend>Personal</legend>
      <div class="form-group row">
       <label class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Firstname</label>
       <div class="col-sm-10">
        <p class="form-control-static">{{parent.firstname}}</p>
       </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group row">
       <label class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Lastname</label>
       <div class="col-sm-10">
        <p class="form-control-static">{{parent.lastname}}</p>
       </div>
      </div>
     </fieldset>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
```

As you can see I am using an accordion, it is a personal touch to have a nice layout of added items and to have a nice overview of all items.

Hope you can help me in this issue or give me some usefull links
Thanks!

Comment: How are they passed to the .NET controller or AngularJS controller?

Comment: @cnorthfield not yet to a .NET controller, that is the way I am looking for.
They go to a angularjs controller by a form
    <form name="parentsFrm" ng-submit="addParent()">
    <input type="text" name="Firstname" ng-model="Firstname" required class="form-control">
    <input type="text" name="Lastname" ng-model="Lastname" required class="form-control">
    </form>